# CSS animations with variable times

Tags: css, animation

I'm working on a page that will swap out between 2 different texts in a `<span>` block. I need the first `<span>` to display for 10-15 mins, and then the second `<span>` to display for just a few seconds and then scroll back to the first `<span>`.

I was using CSS animations and keyframes but I can only figure out how to make the times the same for both, so I can make both show up for 15 mins and I can't separate the times.

````
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif';
}
.rw-sentence{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.rw-sentence span{

}
.rw-words{
    display: inline;
}
.rw-words-1 span{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: rotateWord 300s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) { 
    animation: rotateWord2 5s linear infinite 0s;
        animation-delay: 100s; 
}


}
@keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    1% { opacity: 1; }
    30% { opacity: 1; }
    31% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }

    @keyframes rotateWord2 {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    1% { opacity: 1; }
    98% { opacity: 1; }
    99% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; } ```
````

Answer (score 1):

It required a bit of detective work to provide this example, as you didn't provide your corresponding HTML markup, but here's a working example that will show word1 for 10 seconds and word2 for 5 seconds. You'l have to play with (or rather calculate) your percentage values to adapt it to your requirements, but you should be able to get the gist.

Both animations share the same length, and you calculate the percentage values depending on your target time. So in this case, 10 seconds of 15 seconds total equals 66.666...%

```css
.rw-words-1 span{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) { 
    animation: rotateWord2 15s linear infinite 0s;
}

@keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    65.9% { opacity: 1; }
    66% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes rotateWord2 {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    65.9% { opacity: 0; }
    66% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="rw-words-1">
  <span>word1</span>
  <span>word2</span>
</div>
```